# CubeMX & System Workbench Error "selected processor does not support ´dsb 0xF´in Thumb mode"

Tags: stm32, cubemx

When I create a new Project with STM32CubeMX for STM32F103RCT and open it with System Workbench i get this Error:

[Error Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU68L.png)

In a similar Question they said to add "-mcpu=cortex-m3" but where???
similar Question: [STM32Cube - project does not build (Selected processor does not support Thumb mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419416/stm32cube-project-does-not-build-selected-processor-does-not-support-thumb-mo)

Any Ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:
I tried to select a target and got this:
[Properties-Settings-Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PunrQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

select the correct processor in the **project properties**

Comment: I tried to select a Target in Properties-Settings-Target. The Button "Define board target" is not clickable

Comment: do not define board